# Empty column in a row result of Sqlite + Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encoding, character-encoding

I'm in a problem with sqlite.

I put my pre-loaded sqlite database on my application, everythings works fine, the connection is Ok, the existence of the database is ok. But, when i query with select some rows return empty data in just one column. I've checked my database, and the only strange thing in that row is the characters in that row/column.

How can i query my database to return all the results even the rows with strange characters?

Here is my code where i tried to get the rows.

```
public List<Song> getAllSongs(){
        List<Song> result = new ArrayList<Song>();
        String selectQuery = "select a.Name, b.Name from Song as a, Artist as b where a.IdArtist = b._id order by a.Name";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Song song = new Song();
                song.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                song.setArtist(cursor.getString(1));
                result.add(song);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And also, my meaning of strange characters are " ' ", " ñ ", ...

Comment: and what have you tried?show your java code, please.

Comment: Even more important: Define "strange characters" and give an example.

Comment: I've updated with my code to get the rows, when I try cursor.getString(1) it's empty :(

Comment: I also explained my definition of "strange characters"

Comment: I doubt this will make a difference, but since both your columns have the same name you might want to try modifying your select statement to use `a.Name as SongName, b.Name as ArtistName` in the projection

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't solve the problem. Is there any problem if i put a link with the database???

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS or the ADB to move the entire database to your computer and examine it there.

```
adb pull /data/data/com.your.package.name/databases/dbname
```

Then use something like sqlite on the PC to access it with a command line.

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: Yes i did that, i've checked the database and that row/column is not empty

Comment: Looking at the "strange characters" as you defined them. It looks to me like a character encoding issue.  I won't be of any use in that area.

Comment: The problem is that i need to show the data with those characters. The strange thing is that the row/column returns empty string

Comment: I wonder...  Can you throw a "getType(1) in there and see what type it is?  4 is a blob, 3 is a string.  You may have to retrieve it as a ByteArray or use copyStringToBuffer and give it a buffer to put the column in then convert it to String after retrieving it.

Comment: Try the copyStringToBuffer call.  At first I was thinking that may help, but now I'm not so sure.  I would also try getting it as a bytearray or byte stream.  Can you try getBlob and giving it a byte array?  I haven't run into this before and am thinking of things I've done with mysql when I have foreign chars.